# nginx regex match with multiple possibility and concat in one group

Tags: regex, nginx

This is my regex location for nginx.

```
location ~ "^/live/midrate/v1/rates/((?:[A-Z]{6})-(?:SPT|ON|W[1-3]|M(?:[1-9][0-9]?)|Y[2-5])-(?:[DO])-(?:[ON]))$"
```

The request URI is

```
live/midrate/v1/rates/GBPUSD-SPT-D-O
```

and result is

```
Match found  Capture Groups 1: GBPUSD-SPT-D-O 2:  3:  4:  5:  6:
```

firstly I want to have 1 group instead of multiple groups which are empty now and I need to support comma-separated with same pattern.

```
live/midrate/v1/rates/GBPUSD-SPT-D-O,EURUSD-M1-D-O,EURGP-SPT-O-O
```

and the response should be

```
Match found  Capture Groups 1: GBPUSD-SPT-D-O,EURUSD-M1-D-O,EURGBP-SPT-O-O
```

Comment: I don't see where those other capture groups are coming from. All the rest of your groups are non-capturing.

Comment: `EURGP-SPT-D-O` doesn't match your pattern because `EURGP` is only 5 characters, the pattern requires 6 characters there. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes it's 6 char! I update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one as well and it works.

```
^/live/midrate/v1/rates/((?:([A-Z]{6})-(SPT|ON|TN|W[1-3]|M[1-9][0-9]?|Y[2-5])-([DO])-([ON]),?){1,})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/PuEjA0/1)

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for capturing a comma-delimited sequence of a pattern is

```
(pat(?:,pat)*)
```

where `pat` is the pattern for a single iteration.

So in your case it would be:

```
^/live/midrate/v1/rates/((?:[A-Z]{6})-(?:SPT|ON|W[1-3]|M(?:[1-9][0-9]?)|Y[2-5])-(?:[DO])-(?:[ON])(?:,(?:[A-Z]{6})-(?:SPT|ON|W[1-3]|M(?:[1-9][0-9]?)|Y[2-5])-(?:[DO])-(?:[ON]))*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cL6aYh/1)